# Docker-Compose issue with keycloak + Postgresql deployed to ECR fargate awsvpc network giving error unknownhostException : postgres

Tags: keycloak, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am using Docker-Compose similar to below link :

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-postgres.yml

Deploying to ECR fargate but getting unknownhostexception :

Below values tried with The ECS environment variable for Postgress.

DB_ADDR = postgres

DB_ADDR = localhost:5432

Comment: Hi Steps which i am doing is below : 1. docker-compose build ... 2.  docker push <image> to ecr .. Step 3 : ECS points to ECR image and then run the image..  Note : Cluster is already created via CF templates..

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us more how you are deploying to ECS? It's unclear if you are building native CloudFormation to mimic what the compose file does or if you are using the [Docker Compose / ECS integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/) Docker recently made available.

I have tried with the latter and it just works out of the box for me with the compose file you linked above. You just create an ECS context with docker, you switch to it and then you `docker compose up`. It just works:

```
$ docker compose up   
WARNING volumes.driver: unsupported attribute        
[+] Running 25/25
 ⠿ downloads                                   CreateComplete                                                                                          606.2s
 ⠿ DefaultNetwork                              CreateComplete                                                                                            5.0s
 ⠿ KeycloakTCP8080TargetGroup                  CreateComplete                                                                                            1.0s
 ⠿ PostgresTaskExecutionRole                   CreateComplete                                                                                           19.0s
 ⠿ LoadBalancer                                CreateComplete                                                                                          514.7s
 ⠿ PostgresdataFilesystem                      CreateComplete                                                                                            6.0s
 ⠿ CloudMap                                    CreateComplete                                                                                           47.0s
 ⠿ LogGroup                                    CreateComplete                                                                                            3.0s
 ⠿ KeycloakTaskExecutionRole                   CreateComplete                                                                                           19.0s
 ⠿ Cluster                                     CreateComplete                                                                                            6.0s
 ⠿ Default8080Ingress                          CreateComplete                                                                                            0.0s
 ⠿ DefaultNetworkIngress                       CreateComplete                                                                                            0.0s
 ⠿ PostgresdataAccessPoint                     CreateComplete                                                                                            6.6s
 ⠿ PostgresdataNFSMountTargetOnSubnetd22cbcb4  CreateComplete                                                                                           93.0s
 ⠿ PostgresdataNFSMountTargetOnSubnet20545308  CreateComplete                                                                                           93.0s
 ⠿ PostgresdataNFSMountTargetOnSubnetd74c158c  CreateComplete                                                                                           93.0s
 ⠿ PostgresdataNFSMountTargetOnSubnet0ad86842  CreateComplete                                                                                           92.0s
 ⠿ PostgresTaskRole                            CreateComplete                                                                                           20.0s
 ⠿ KeycloakTaskDefinition                      CreateComplete                                                                                            3.0s
 ⠿ PostgresTaskDefinition                      CreateComplete                                                                                            1.7s
 ⠿ KeycloakServiceDiscoveryEntry               CreateComplete                                                                                            2.0s
 ⠿ PostgresServiceDiscoveryEntry               CreateComplete                                                                                            2.0s
 ⠿ PostgresService                             CreateComplete                                                                                           87.8s
 ⠿ KeycloakTCP8080Listener                     CreateComplete                                                                                            2.1s
 ⠿ KeycloakService                             CreateComplete                                                                                           78.4s

$ docker compose ps 
NAME                                              SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
task/downloads/09d102af7f3f4fc2a02d43dd01021b61   postgres            Running             
task/downloads/33854c524ad3415ea3b68530a878b062   keycloak            Running             downl-LoadB-1X6HK6A4UBJKG-d5567a0aaa2f2a27.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8080->8080/tcp

$
```

If you connect to the endpoint specified in the `docker compose ps` you will see your Keycloak app up and running on AWS.

PS to be clear, you need to use `docker compose` (aka compose v2) and not the traditional `docker-compose` binary. See the blog I linked for more info.

Comment: Hi Steps which i am doing is below : 1. docker-compose build ... 2.  docker push <image> to ecr .. Step 3 : ECS points to ECR image and then run the image..  Note : Cluster is already created via CF templates..

Comment: I may be missing something but your are talking about steps that do not align/fit perfectly with the compose file you shared. I noted now you said "similar" but without the PROPER compose file and proper list of commands you are issuing and proper error message it will be hard to imagine what you are doing (and how to fix it) :)